# Why are capacitors and inductors called that way?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I do understand that electrical resistance describes somehow the material resistance to electrons flow but I don't see the meaning behind the names capacitors and inductors (if there is any and it should I guess!)

Comment: Because capacitors have charge storing capacity, and inductors induce electromotive force in conductors when current runs through them. But how is this a question about history?

Comment: @Conifold Just thought it was a historical question because it traces the origins of the words and I couldn't find an explicit answer anywhere.

Comment: Look at [Wikipedia's inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance) and [capacitance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance) articles.

Comment: @Conifold Okay, you're right I should have looked up Wikipedia articles before.